# How to position a bootstrap modal to open from where the button is

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and AngularJs. 
I am trying to use bootstrap modal dialog box to display additional details in a column of a table. I want the bootstrap modal to popup from where the details button in every row is but I can't seem to change the default position of the modal. It always pops up at the top and not where the mouse was clicked. Is there any way to re position it so that it pops up from right where the button is so that it looks more relevant to a particular element and less like an alert box.
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like yo need [A Tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) instead the modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use tooltip with html template and you can change the trigger to click so it will resolve your problem